# Install Puppet Server 7 on AWS ARM instance

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, arm, puppet

We’ve encountered a ruby error during Puppet Server 7 installation on AWS Graviton (arm) instances with Ubuntu 18.04 (ami-0c925af1500feb25d) and 20.04 (ami-08b6fc871ad49ff41). 
Puppet was installed according to the [official manual](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7.4/server/install_from_packages.html), without any additional configuration.
By the way, on amd64 instances it works properly.
During puppetserver.service start we have following errors:
**Syslog**:

```
 Starting puppetserver Service...
 Puppet::Error: Cannot determine basic system flavour
            <main> at /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/feature/base.rb:19
           require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974
           require at uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
   <module:Puppet> at /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:98
            <main> at /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:42
           require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974
           require at uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
            <main> at uri:classloader:/puppetserver-lib/puppet/server.rb:1
           require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974
           require at uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
            <main> at uri:classloader:/puppetserver-lib/puppet/server/master.rb:1
           require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974
           require at uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
            <main> at <script>:1
 Execution error (RuntimeError) at RUBY/<main> (/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/feature/base.rb:19).
 (Error) Cannot determine basic system flavour
 Full report at:
 /tmp/clojure-2104485397975789536.edn
 Background process 1437 exited before start had completed
 puppetserver.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
 puppetserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Failed to start puppetserver Service.
 puppetserver.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
 puppetserver.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5689.
 Stopped puppetserver Service.
```

**puppetserver.log**:

```
Logging initialized @5753ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
Initializing Scheduler Service
Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.
RAMJobStore initialized.
Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) '536c68b8-9037-4bef-bca8-d8c28bd9ba6e' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

Quartz scheduler '536c68b8-9037-4bef-bca8-d8c28bd9ba6e' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.2
Scheduler 536c68b8-9037-4bef-bca8-d8c28bd9ba6e_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
Initializing web server(s).
Registering status callback function for service 'puppet-profiler', version 7.0.3
Initializing the JRuby service
Initializing the JRuby service
Creating JRubyInstance with id 1.
Registering status callback function for service 'jruby-metrics', version 7.0.3
No code-id-command set for versioned-code-service. Code-id will be nil.
No code-content-command set for versioned-code-service. Attempting to fetch code content will fail.


Error during service init!!!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to borrow JRubyInstance from pool
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__34136$borrow_from_pool_BANG__STAR___34141$fn__34142.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:313)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__34136$borrow_from_pool_BANG__STAR___34141.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:300)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__34183$borrow_from_pool_with_timeout__34188$fn__34189.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:348)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__34183$borrow_from_pool_with_timeout__34188.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:337)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.instance_pool$fn__34947.invokeStatic(instance_pool.clj:48)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.instance_pool$fn__34947.invoke(instance_pool.clj:10)
    at puppetlabs.services.protocols.jruby_pool$fn__34772$G__34685__34779.invoke(jruby_pool.clj:3)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.jruby_core$fn__35861$borrow_from_pool_with_timeout__35866$fn__35867.invoke(jruby_core.clj:222)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.jruby_core$fn__35861$borrow_from_pool_with_timeout__35866.invoke(jruby_core.clj:209)
    at puppetlabs.services.config.puppet_server_config_core$fn__43588$get_puppet_config__43593$fn__43594$fn__43595.invoke(puppet_server_config_core.clj:107)
    at puppetlabs.services.config.puppet_server_config_core$fn__43588$get_puppet_config__43593$fn__43594.invoke(puppet_server_config_core.clj:107)
    at puppetlabs.services.config.puppet_server_config_core$fn__43588$get_puppet_config__43593.invoke(puppet_server_config_core.clj:102)
    at puppetlabs.services.config.puppet_server_config_service$reify__43623$service_fnk__5000__auto___positional$reify__43634.init(puppet_server_config_service.clj:25)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services$fn__4824$G__4816__4827.invoke(services.clj:9)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services$fn__4824$G__4815__4831.invoke(services.clj:9)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14371$run_lifecycle_fn_BANG___14378$fn__14379.invoke(internal.clj:196)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14371$run_lifecycle_fn_BANG___14378.invoke(internal.clj:179)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14400$run_lifecycle_fns__14405$fn__14406.invoke(internal.clj:229)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14400$run_lifecycle_fns__14405.invoke(internal.clj:206)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15015$build_app_STAR___15024$fn$reify__15036.init(internal.clj:602)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15063$boot_services_for_app_STAR__STAR___15070$fn__15071$fn__15073.invoke(internal.clj:630)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15063$boot_services_for_app_STAR__STAR___15070$fn__15071.invoke(internal.clj:629)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__15063$boot_services_for_app_STAR__STAR___15070.invoke(internal.clj:623)
    at clojure.core$partial$fn__5841.invoke(core.clj:2630)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14445$initialize_lifecycle_worker__14456$fn__14457$fn__14607$state_machine__11603__auto____14632$fn__14635.invoke(internal.clj:249)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14445$initialize_lifecycle_worker__14456$fn__14457$fn__14607$state_machine__11603__auto____14632.invoke(internal.clj:249)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invokeStatic(ioc_macros.clj:973)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:972)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.invokeStatic(ioc_macros.clj:977)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:975)
    at clojure.core.async$ioc_alts_BANG_$fn__11818.invoke(async.clj:384)
    at clojure.core.async$do_alts$fn__11758$fn__11761.invoke(async.clj:253)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel$fn__6422$fn__6423.invoke(channels.clj:95)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Caused by: org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (Error) Cannot determine basic system flavour
    at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedEvalUnitImpl.run(EmbedEvalUnitImpl.java:131)
    at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runUnit(ScriptingContainer.java:1295)
    at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet(ScriptingContainer.java:1288)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:167)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:102)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby.jruby_puppet_core$fn__36162$get_initialize_pool_instance_fn__36167$fn__36168$fn__36169.invoke(jruby_puppet_core.clj:118)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__33936$create_pool_instance_BANG___33945$fn__33948.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:256)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__33936$create_pool_instance_BANG___33945.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:225)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34354$add_instance__34359$fn__34363.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:52)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34354$add_instance__34359.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:47)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34381$prime_pool_BANG___34386$fn__34390.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:76)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34381$prime_pool_BANG___34386.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:61)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.instance_pool$fn__34943$fn__34944.invoke(instance_pool.clj:16)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$shutdown_on_error_STAR_.invokeStatic(internal.clj:403)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$shutdown_on_error_STAR_.invoke(internal.clj:378)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$shutdown_on_error_STAR_.invokeStatic(internal.clj:388)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$shutdown_on_error_STAR_.invoke(internal.clj:378)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14866$shutdown_service__14871$fn$reify__14873$service_fnk__5000__auto___positional$reify__14878.shutdown_on_error(internal.clj:448)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14796$G__14792__14804.invoke(internal.clj:411)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14796$G__14791__14813.invoke(internal.clj:411)
    at clojure.core$partial$fn__5839.invoke(core.clj:2625)
    at clojure.core$partial$fn__5839.invoke(core.clj:2624)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34328$send_agent__34333$fn__34334$agent_fn__34335.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:41)
    at clojure.core$binding_conveyor_fn$fn__5754.invoke(core.clj:2033)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
    at clojure.lang.Agent$Action.doRun(Agent.java:114)
    at clojure.lang.Agent$Action.run(Agent.java:163)
    ... 3 common frames omitted


Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RuntimeError: (Error) Cannot determine basic system flavour
    at RUBY.<main>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/feature/base.rb:19)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974)
    at uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.rubygems.core_ext.kernel_require.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54)
    at RUBY.<module:Puppet>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:98)
    at RUBY.<main>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:42)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974)
    at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54)
    at RUBY.<main>(uri:classloader:/puppetserver-lib/puppet/server.rb:1)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974)
    at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54)
    at RUBY.<main>(uri:classloader:/puppetserver-lib/puppet/server/master.rb:1)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974)
    at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54)
    at RUBY.<main>(<script>:1)


shutdown-on-error triggered because of exception!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There was a problem adding a JRubyInstance to the pool.
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34354$add_instance__34359$fn__34363.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:58)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34354$add_instance__34359.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:47)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34381$prime_pool_BANG___34386$fn__34390.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:76)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34381$prime_pool_BANG___34386.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:61)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.instance_pool$fn__34943$fn__34944.invoke(instance_pool.clj:16)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$shutdown_on_error_STAR_.invokeStatic(internal.clj:403)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$shutdown_on_error_STAR_.invoke(internal.clj:378)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$shutdown_on_error_STAR_.invokeStatic(internal.clj:388)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$shutdown_on_error_STAR_.invoke(internal.clj:378)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14866$shutdown_service__14871$fn$reify__14873$service_fnk__5000__auto___positional$reify__14878.shutdown_on_error(internal.clj:448)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14796$G__14792__14804.invoke(internal.clj:411)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14796$G__14791__14813.invoke(internal.clj:411)
    at clojure.core$partial$fn__5839.invoke(core.clj:2625)
    at clojure.core$partial$fn__5839.invoke(core.clj:2624)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34328$send_agent__34333$fn__34334$agent_fn__34335.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:41)
    at clojure.core$binding_conveyor_fn$fn__5754.invoke(core.clj:2033)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
    at clojure.lang.Agent$Action.doRun(Agent.java:114)
    at clojure.lang.Agent$Action.run(Agent.java:163)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Caused by: org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (Error) Cannot determine basic system flavour
    at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedEvalUnitImpl.run(EmbedEvalUnitImpl.java:131)
    at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runUnit(ScriptingContainer.java:1295)
    at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet(ScriptingContainer.java:1288)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:167)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:102)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby.jruby_puppet_core$fn__36162$get_initialize_pool_instance_fn__36167$fn__36168$fn__36169.invoke(jruby_puppet_core.clj:118)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__33936$create_pool_instance_BANG___33945$fn__33948.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:256)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_internal$fn__33936$create_pool_instance_BANG___33945.invoke(jruby_internal.clj:225)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34354$add_instance__34359$fn__34363.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:52)
    ... 22 common frames omitted


Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RuntimeError: (Error) Cannot determine basic system flavour
    at RUBY.<main>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/feature/base.rb:19)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974)
    at uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.rubygems.core_ext.kernel_require.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54)
    at RUBY.<module:Puppet>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:98)
    at RUBY.<main>(/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:42)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974)
    at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54)
    at RUBY.<main>(uri:classloader:/puppetserver-lib/puppet/server.rb:1)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974)
    at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54)
    at RUBY.<main>(uri:classloader:/puppetserver-lib/puppet/server/master.rb:1)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:974)
    at RUBY.require(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54)
    at RUBY.<main>(<script>:1)


Beginning shutdown sequence
JRuby Metrics Service: stopping metrics sampler job
JRuby Metrics Service: stopped metrics sampler job
Draining JRuby pool.


Encountered error during shutdown sequence
java.lang.InterruptedException: Lock can't be granted because a pill has been inserted
    at com.puppetlabs.jruby_utils.pool.JRubyPool.lockWithTimeout(JRubyPool.java:368)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:167)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:102)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34462$borrow_all_jrubies__34467$fn__34468$fn__34469.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:128)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34462$borrow_all_jrubies__34467$fn__34468.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:127)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34462$borrow_all_jrubies__34467.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:119)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34542$drain_and_refill_pool_BANG___34551$fn__34554.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:190)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34542$drain_and_refill_pool_BANG___34551.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:172)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34583$flush_pool_for_shutdown_BANG___34588$fn__34589.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:211)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.jruby_agents$fn__34583$flush_pool_for_shutdown_BANG___34588.invoke(jruby_agents.clj:199)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.instance_pool$fn__34959.invokeStatic(instance_pool.clj:20)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.impl.instance_pool$fn__34959.invoke(instance_pool.clj:10)
    at puppetlabs.services.protocols.jruby_pool$fn__34737$G__34697__34742.invoke(jruby_pool.clj:3)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.jruby_core$fn__35936$flush_pool_for_shutdown_BANG___35941$fn__35942.invoke(jruby_core.clj:250)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby_pool_manager.jruby_core$fn__35936$flush_pool_for_shutdown_BANG___35941.invoke(jruby_core.clj:245)
    at puppetlabs.services.jruby.jruby_puppet_service$reify__36714$service_fnk__5000__auto___positional$reify__36728.stop(jruby_puppet_service.clj:50)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services$fn__4850$G__4820__4853.invoke(services.clj:9)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services$fn__4850$G__4819__4857.invoke(services.clj:9)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14371$run_lifecycle_fn_BANG___14378$fn__14379.invoke(internal.clj:196)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14371$run_lifecycle_fn_BANG___14378.invoke(internal.clj:179)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14923$shutdown_BANG___14928$fn__14929$shutdown_fn__14931$fn__14946.invoke(internal.clj:459)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14923$shutdown_BANG___14928$fn__14929$shutdown_fn__14931.invoke(internal.clj:458)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14445$initialize_lifecycle_worker__14456$fn__14457$fn__14607$state_machine__11603__auto____14632$fn__14635$fn__14649.invoke(internal.clj:274)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14445$initialize_lifecycle_worker__14456$fn__14457$fn__14607$state_machine__11603__auto____14632$fn__14635.invoke(internal.clj:258)
    at puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.internal$fn__14445$initialize_lifecycle_worker__14456$fn__14457$fn__14607$state_machine__11603__auto____14632.invoke(internal.clj:249)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invokeStatic(ioc_macros.clj:973)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:972)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.invokeStatic(ioc_macros.clj:977)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:975)
    at clojure.core.async$ioc_alts_BANG_$fn__11818.invoke(async.clj:384)
    at clojure.core.async$do_alts$fn__11758$fn__11761.invoke(async.clj:253)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel$fn__6438.invoke(channels.clj:135)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Shutting down web server(s).
Shutting down Scheduler Service
Scheduler 536c68b8-9037-4bef-bca8-d8c28bd9ba6e_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
Scheduler 536c68b8-9037-4bef-bca8-d8c28bd9ba6e_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
Scheduler 536c68b8-9037-4bef-bca8-d8c28bd9ba6e_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
Scheduler Service shutdown complete.
Finished shutdown sequence
```

How to fix this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Make sure `/tmp` isn't mounted w/ `noexec`

Comment: My current /etc/fstab: 
`LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs /  ext4 defaults,discard 0 1`
`LABEL=UEFI /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1`

Comment: The exception at the bottom of the stack is `org.jruby.exceptions.RuntimeError: (Error) Cannot determine basic system flavour`.  That's coming from JRuby, not from Puppet proper, and I'm inclined to think that it means the JRuby bundled with your puppetserver package does not support ARM.  If so then that would constitute a packaging error, presumably by Puppet, Inc -- unless you've somehow installed a wrong-arch package.  This diagnosis is somewhat speculative, but it still might be worthwhile to file a ticket against Puppet.

Comment: It seems that @JohnBollinger's assumption is right. I had 2 fresh EC2 servers, one arm and one x86. Worked flawless on first effort on the x86 and not at all on the arm machine (same errors that OP reported).